Integer File Not Opening Correctly
I apologize that this is probably a question with a very simple explanation, but I can't seem to find it.  I'm currently trying to build a basic database with C.  I need to save a structure-linked list along with the size of said linkededlist, so that I know how large the list is, when I open it.  I'm planning to write the size of the list as an integer, along with the linkedlist.  For some reason, even with the linked list commented out, the program fails to read the file.  The relevant code is below:
#define Opennamefile Movienames=fopen("movienames.txt", "wb")
#define Closenamefile fclose(Movienames)
FILE *Movienames=NULL;

int openfile(int *flistsize)
{
int reject=0;
Opennamefile;
if((fread(&flistsize, sizeof(int), 1, Movienames))!=1) reject=-690;
//if(fread(&head, sizeof(identity), flistsize, Movienames)!=1) reject=-690;
if((Movienames==NULL) || (reject==-690))
{
fputs("Error opening the name file\n", stderr);
printf("%d", *flistsize);
}

return 1;
}

int savenamefile(int flistsize)
{
    int reject=0;
    if(fwrite(&flistsize, sizeof(int), 1, Movienames)!=1) reject=-690;
    //if(fwrite(&head, sizeof(identity), flistsize, Movienames)!=flistsize) reject=-690;
Closenamefile;
    if(Movienames==EOF || reject==-690)
    {
        fputs("Error closing file", stderr);
        return -69;
    }
    puts("successfully closed/saved file");
    return 1;
}


Please format your code using standard indentation conventions.

I don't think your macros are useful here & they may hurt. They led me astray at first. Getting over that, I notice that your openfile() opens a file for writing destroying any contents if the file already exists. It then attempts to read from that file.  Not sure what you intended, but that's not it.

Use enum values, named constants, or macros for your error codes. Avoid hard-coded magic numbers, no matter how entertaining you think that is. Those numbers have absolutely zero meaning.

I'm attempting to open the file in read/write mode in binary, but I'm unsure if that's possible in C.  Then at inception, I want to read the file.  At the end, I want to overwrite the existing file with the new data.  Might have to do a read, then close.  Then write, then close?

Aside: the shown code suggests the OP is unaware-of (therefore not using) an "object pool". Each node of the reported "linked list" will reside as an isolated fragment, likely scattered in heap storage. "Bulk processing" i/o of all nodes in a single read or write operation is simply wrong.

r+ instead of w for read/write mode. Read docs at the link I previously provided. However this will lead to other issues. Easy issue is switching between reading and writing. The link will tell you how to handle that. Second issue is that the revised file might need to be shorter than the original. That is a much bigger deal. Better to write a a new file & replace the old file with it. There are more issues in the details of saving/loading linked list nodes, but that's getting too far ahead.

And yes, @Fe2O3 is entirely correct that the commented out code that attempts to read or write all the nodes in a single call won't work. They aren't contiguous in memory like that and any pointers they contain do not remain valid.

Based on what I'm reading, I'd essentially have to save a linked list  as a series of structures?  Then to open, I'd essentially need another loop to recreate the linked list and related pointers?

@Ratdude Based on what you've just asked, you need to go back and review the chapters, exercises and concepts that your question reveals you have not assimilated. Without a solid foundation, no superstructure will stand for long.

In your openfile function, flistsize is already a pointer to the target that you want to write to. But you are referencing that again, meaning you'll be writing to the memory that holds the pointer value itself.
To fix that issue, remove the &:
fread(flistsize, sizeof(int), 1, Movienames)

